# How can a component determine if a full-screen iAd is being presented?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, iad, interstitial

I'm making a UI component to display an alert view periodically (think [iVersion](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion)).

When a full-screen ad is launched and screen control is lost, I want to prevent popups and notifications (which would otherwise obscure the ad).

**How can my component determine if the app is presenting a full-screen ad to prevent/postpone the alert views?**

---

There is the delegate method

```
- (BOOL) interstitialAdActionShouldBegin:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
                   willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
```

and the ad property

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isActionInProgress) 
    BOOL actionInProgress
```

and the UIViewController property

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isPresentingFullScreenAd) 
    BOOL presentingFullScreenAd
```

but my component will not have direct access to the AdBanner object nor know which view controller is presenting the ad, if at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: How would you be inspecting the view hierarchy if not by poling?

Comment: @Paulw11 Polling = polling `actionInProgress`, of course ;)

Comment: Isn't this what [presentingFullScreenAd](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentingFullScreenAd) is for?

Comment: @DanielStorm You're saying that since we can't know which UIViewController is presenting the ad, if at all, then we traverse the view hierarchy, find all the view controllers, and test them for this property?